# Abrir un programa( de consola) dentro de un WindowsForm en c#

Tags: c#, formularios

Querría abrir un proyecto que tengo hecho en C# que al ejecutarlos se hace en un terminal (una practica de la universidad) dentro de otro proyecto de Windowsform que sera mi PracticeLauncher (Lanzador de practicas) donde se pueda ver pulsando un boton el terminal dentro del form algo asi
[image: Esto es lo que quiero pero en vez de notepad un terminal con mi practica]
Ya he intentado cambiar simplemente el exe de la direccion pero al pulsar el boton se abre en una ventana nueva y no dentro

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = Process.Start("cmd.exe");
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowHandle);
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);


}
```

ese es el codigo que utilizo y el error es este

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Mensaje =
> WaitForInputIdle failed.  This could be because the process does not
> have a graphical interface.

Comment: Yo personalmente no te recomiendo hacerlo la verdad. No te va a dar mas que quebraderos de cabeza. Microsoft tenia algo en el pasado similar a eso (interfaz MDI) y se abandonó entre otras cosas por los problemas que da.

Answer (score 0):

Realizar lo que dices es complicado, pero encontré algo que te pueda servir y es que se abre alternativamente la consola junto con tu windows form...

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

La fuente esta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4363184/4668184)

Lo que tu hiciste es llamar un proceso del sistema operativo.

En el ejemplo esta invocando la consola desde el evento load del form.

puedes hacerlo desde el evento click de un botón del form. Por Ejemplo

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
    }
```